# Facebook crashes Firefox

Tags: firefox, facebook

Facebook loads, will let me scroll down until eventually connection is lost, Firefox crashes and requires System Monitor to Kill Process. 
I don't know what extra info you may need. I'll add details on request.

Comment: Maybe you can find some errormessages in `~/.xsession-errors`. Just type `cat ~/.xsession-errors` in a terminal and append the (relevant) output to your question.

Comment: Raise a bug on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org) add some of the bp- lines from about:crashes to the bug.